# Vertical Alignment of Everything inside a Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns inside a row, col-lg-8 and col-lg-4,

I have an Image stored in the col-lg-8, and inside the col-lg-4 I have text and another small image. What I would like it to do is the column on the right with text and the image to be vertically aligned in the middle of the page regardless of the size of the photo on the right. If the page shrinks, then I want the text to be below the image with only about 50px padding between the image and text.

I have tried using inline-block but that hasn't worked for me so far

Here is my code so far:

```
<div class="row">
<div class= "col-lg-8">
    <img src=".../../2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>

<div class= "col-lg-4 inline-block">
    <h3 style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque non volutpat lorem. Etiam ac suscipit nisi, id porttitor ante. Suspendisse erat velit, congue vel ante in, fermentum porta arcu. Donec enim velit, ultrices sed orci vitae, maximus tincidunt quam. Nullam at nulla velit. Etiam commodo quam quis nisi hendrerit, sit amet rhoncus felis euismod. Nulla sed semper enim. Nunc in arcu ac diam malesuada pellentesque sed et tellus. Aenean lobortis, elit ut sollicitudin maximus, justo leo volutpat arcu, vitae sodales nisi lectus at lacus. Maecenas id placerat mi. Sed tristique tempor finibus.</h3>
    <img src="../../3.jpg>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For vertical alignment property, you need to set the display property of the parent div to 'table' and 'table-cell' to the inner div.

Another way to vertically align an element is by absolute positioning.

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
}

.child,
.image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child">

    <h3 id="text">Text alignment</h3>

  </div>

</div>
```

You can use this to vertically align an entire div (in your case the image and the text) and use a separate media query for mobile devices.

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 991px)
    {

    #text{
      display: block;
      position: static;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
```